# How do I call a specific python function in a file from the command line?

Tags: python

Say there is the following function in a file called fb_auth_token.py

```
def get_fb_access_token(email, password):
...
return ...
```

How would I run this from bash? `python fb_auth_token.py get_fb_access?`. How do I call just the one specific function?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to do. You could for example just call it in your Python file: `print(get_fb_access_token(email, password))`. And then run `python fb_auth_token.py`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could either call python with the command option:

```
python -c "from file_name import function;function()"
```

or if you want this function to be called every time you execute the script you could add the line

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    function()
```

This will then only execute this function if the file is executed directly (i.e. you can still import it into another script without "function" being called).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

`python -c 'import fb_auth_token; print fb_auth_token.get_fb_access_token("email", "password")'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-c` command line argument. For example:

```
python -c 'import fb_auth_token; fb_auth_token.get_fb_access_token("email", "password")'
```